An unusual binomial coefficient identity
I derived the following family of binomial coefficient identities rather indirectly for natural $t \ge 2$ (though it seems to hold more generally).  I was hoping someone out there might know if this result exists in the literature, or perhaps come up with a more straightforward proof than mine.  I paged through the H. W. Gould volumes of identities but didn't see it, though there were a few that seemed similar.
$$
\binom {n}{k}=
(t+1 + t n )\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i \,  
\dfrac{
\displaystyle
\binom{t + (t-1) n + k }{i}  
\binom{n+1}{k-i}
}
{(i+1) \displaystyle
\binom{ t+1 + t n + k }{i+1}}
$$
Just to check that I've transcribed it OK, let's work an example, how about $\binom{5}{2}$ with $t=3$?  That's $n=5, k=2$.
\begin{align*}
%% &
%% (t+1 + t n )\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i \,  
%% \dfrac{
%% \displaystyle
%% \binom{t + (t-1) n + k }{i}  
%% \binom{n+1}{k-i}
%%}
%%{(i+1) \displaystyle
%%\binom{ t+1 + t n + k }{i+1}}
%%\\
\binom{5}{2} &= {} 
(3+1+3(5) )
\sum_{i=0}^2 
\\ & \quad (-1)^i \,  
\dfrac{
\displaystyle
\binom{3 + (3-1) (5) + 2 }{i}  
\binom{5+1}{2-i}
}
{(i+1) \displaystyle
\binom{ 3+1 + 3 (5) + 2 }{i+1} }
\\
%%% &= 
%%% 19 \sum_{i=0}^2 (-1)^i \,  
%%% \dfrac{
%%% \displaystyle
%%% \binom{15}{i}  
%%% \binom{6}{2-i}
%%% }
%%% {(i+1) \displaystyle
%%% \binom{ 21 }{i+1} }
\\ &= 
19 
\left( \dfrac{
\displaystyle
\binom{15}{0}  
\binom{6}{2}
}
{\displaystyle
1\binom{ 21 }{1} }
 - \dfrac{
\displaystyle
\binom{15}{1}  
\binom{6}{1}
}
{2 \displaystyle
\binom{ 21 }{2} }
+ \dfrac{
\displaystyle
\binom{15}{2}  
\binom{6}{0}
}
{3 \displaystyle
\binom{ 21 }{3} } \right)
\\ &= 
19 
\left( \dfrac{ 1 \cdot 15 }{21 }  - \dfrac{ 15 \cdot 6} {2 \cdot 210 } + \dfrac{ 105 \cdot 1 }{3  \cdot 1330 } \right)
\\&=  19 \cdot \left( \dfrac{5}{7} - \dfrac{3}{14} + \dfrac{1}{38} \right) 
=  19 \cdot \dfrac{10}{19} \quad\checkmark
\end{align*}
Thanks.

Introducing $q=t+1+tn$ the queried identity becomes
$$\frac{1}{q} {n\choose k}
= \sum_{p=0}^k (-1)^p {q-1-n+k\choose p} {n+1\choose k-p}
\frac{1}{p+1} {q+k\choose p+1}^{-1}.$$
Working with the  RHS we see that  the second binomial
coefficient enforces the upper range of the sum
$$[z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} (-1)^p {q-1-n+k\choose p}
\frac{z^p}{p+1} {q+k\choose p+1}^{-1}.$$
This assumes we assign non-singular values for inverse
binomial coefficients  ${n\choose k}^{-1}$  with $k\gt
n$.            Recall             from            MSE
4316307
the following  identity which  was proved  there: with
$1\le k\le n$
$$\frac{1}{k} {n\choose k}^{-1}
= [v^n] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{n-k}.$$
This fits the bill, we  get the exact value when $p+1$
is  in the  range  and  the other  cases  make a  zero
contribution due to the extractor  in $z$ and the fact
that $p=q+k\gt k$  when $q\ge 1.$ Apply to  the sum to
get
$$[z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} [v^{q+k}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{q+k-1}
\sum_{p\ge 0} (-1)^p {q-1-n+k\choose p} z^p (v-1)^{-p}
\\ = [z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} [v^{q+k}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^{q+k-1}
\left[1-\frac{z}{v-1}\right]^{q-1-n+k}
\\ = [z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} [v^{q+k}] \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^n
[v-1-z]^{q-1-n+k}.$$
The contribution from $v$ is
$$\;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{q+k+1}}  \log\frac{1}{1-v} (v-1)^n
[v-1-z]^{q-1-n+k}.$$
Now  put $v/(v-1)=w$  so  that $v=w/(w-1)$  and $dv  =
-1/(w-1)^2 \; dw$ to get
$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{q+k+1}} (w-1)^{q+k+1} \log\frac{1}{1-w} \frac{1}{(w-1)^n} 
[1/(w-1)-z]^{q-1-n+k} \frac{1}{(w-1)^2}.$$
With $q-1-n+k+2+n-q-k-1=0$ this becomes
$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{q+k+1}} \log\frac{1}{1-w} [1-z(w-1)]^{q-1-n+k}
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{q+k+1}} \log\frac{1}{1-w} [1+z-wz]^{q-1-n+k}.$$
Using the generalized binomial theorem and writing
$$[1+z-wz]^{q-1-n+k} = (1+z)^{q-1-n+k}
\left[ 1 - \frac{wz}{1+z}\right]^{q-1-n+k}$$
we obtain
$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{q+k+1}} \log\frac{1}{1-w}
\sum_{p\ge 0} {q-1-n+k\choose p} (1+z)^{q-1-n+k-p}
(-1)^p w^p z^p.$$
With both extractors (upper  range enforced by $w$) we
get a non-singular fraction:
$$\sum_{p=0}^{q+k-1} {q-1-n+k\choose p} 
{q+k-p\choose k-p} (-1)^p \frac{1}{q+k-p}
\\ = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{p=0}^{q+k-1} {q-1-n+k\choose p} 
{q+k-p-1\choose q-1} (-1)^p
\\ = \frac{1}{q} [z^k] (1+z)^{q+k-1} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} {q-1-n+k\choose p} 
\frac{(-1)^p z^p}{(1+z)^p}.$$
Here  we  have  again  extended  to  infinity  as  the
extractor  truncates at  $p=k$  and $k\le  q+k-1.$
Continuing,
$$\frac{1}{q} [z^k] (1+z)^{q+k-1} 
\left[1-\frac{z}{1+z}\right]^{q-1-n+k}
= \frac{1}{q} [z^k] (1+z)^n
= \frac{1}{q} {n\choose k}.$$
This is  the claim.  The boundary conditions  for this
are very  simple and  refer to  integers $q\ge  1$ and
$n\ge k\ge 0.$

Alternate proof
Starting once more from
$$\sum_{p=0}^k (-1)^p {q-1-n+k\choose p} {n+1\choose k-p}
\frac{1}{p+1} {q+k\choose p+1}^{-1}$$
we observe that
$${q-1-n+k\choose p} \frac{1}{p+1} {q+k\choose p+1}^{-1}
= \frac{(q-1-n+k)! \times (q+k-1-p)!}
{(q-1-n+k-p)! \times (q+k)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{n+1} {q+k\choose n+1}^{-1} {q+k-1-p\choose n}$$
which yields for our sum
$$\frac{1}{n+1} {q+k\choose n+1}^{-1}
\sum_{p=0}^k (-1)^p {n+1\choose k-p} {q+k-1-p\choose n}.$$
We point  out here that  this only works  when $q+k\ge
n+1$  for example  with  $q=n+1.$  The first  binomial
coefficient enforces the  range of the sum  and we get
for the sum only
$$[z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} (-1)^p z^p {q+k-1-p\choose q+k-1-n-p}
\\ = [z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} [w^{q+k-1-n}] (1+w)^{q+k-1} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} (-1)^p z^p \frac{w^p}{(1+w)^p}
\\ = [z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} [w^{q+k-1-n}] (1+w)^{q+k-1} 
\frac{1}{1+zw/(1+w)}.$$
The contribution from $w$ is
$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{q+k-n}} (1+w)^{q+k-1} \frac{1}{1+zw/(1+w)}.$$
Now put  $w/(1+w) = u$  so that $w=u/(1-u)$ and  $dw =
1/(1-u)^2 \; du$ to obtain
$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{q+k-n}} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{n-1}} \frac{1}{1+zu}
\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}
\\ = \frac{1}{z} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^{q+k-n}} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{u+1/z}.$$
Here  the  residue at  infinity  is  zero and  we  may
evaluate  using minus  the  residues at  $u=1$ and  at
$u=-1/z$. We get from the latter
$$[z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} \frac{1}{z} (-1)^{q+k-n} z^{q+k-n}
\frac{1}{(1+1/z)^{n+1}}
\\ = [z^k] z^{q+k} (-1)^{q+k-n} = 0.$$
The residue at $u=1$ requires the Leibniz rule:
$$(-1)^n \frac{1}{n!}
\left(\frac{1}{u^{q+k-n}} \frac{1}{(1+zu)^1}\right)^{(n)}
\\ = (-1)^n \frac{1}{n!}
\sum_{p=0}^n {n\choose p}
\frac{(-1)^p (q+k-n)^{\overline{p}}}{u^{q+k-n+p}} 
\frac{(-1)^{n-p} 1^{\overline{n-p}} z^{n-p}}{(1+zu)^{1+n-p}}.$$
Set $u=1$ to get
$$[z^k] (1+z)^{n+1} \sum_{p=0}^n {q+k-1-n+p\choose p}
\frac{z^{n-p}}{(1+z)^{1+n-p}}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^n {q+k-1-n+p\choose p} {p\choose k-n+p}
\\ = [z^{n-k}] \sum_{p=0}^n {q+k-1-n+p\choose p} (1+z)^p
\\ = [z^{n-k}] [w^n] \frac{1}{1-w} 
\sum_{p\ge 0} {q+k-1-n+p\choose p} w^p (1+z)^p
\\ = [z^{n-k}] [w^n] \frac{1}{1-w} \frac{1}{(1-w(1+z))^{q+k-n}}.$$
Here we are making use of the boundary condition $n\ge k.$
Continuing,
$$[z^{n-k}] [w^n] \frac{1}{(1-w)^{q+k-n+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-wz/(1-w)))^{q+k-n}}
\\ = [w^n] \frac{1}{(1-w)^{q+k-n+1}} 
{q-1\choose n-k} \frac{w^{n-k}}{(1-w)^{n-k}}
= {q-1\choose n-k} {k+q\choose k}.$$
We conclude by collecting everything,
$$\frac{1}{n+1} {q+k\choose n+1}^{-1} 
{q-1\choose n-k} {k+q\choose k}.$$
Note that
$$\frac{1}{n+1} {q+k\choose n+1}^{-1} {q-1\choose n-k}
= \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{(n+1)! \times (q-1)!}{(q+k)! \times (n-k)!}
= {n\choose k} \frac{1}{q} {q+k\choose q}^{-1}$$
Multiply by ${k+q\choose k}$ to get the desired result.
